# How to combine 2 response based on condition to get the desired response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have 2 responses like below

```
let response1 = [
    {
        "rnum": 583,
        "status": false,
        "id": 24,
        "action": "set",
        "name": "2726-23",
        "fname": [
            "xy-01"
        ],                
    },
    {
        "rnum": 593,
        "status": false,
        "id": 12,
        "action": "set",
        "name": "2727-5",
        "fname": [
            "yz-01"
        ],                
    }
]
```

```
let response2 = [   
    { 
        "hName": "yz-01",
        "cname": "",
        "dlist": "test"    
    },
    {
        "hName": "xy-01",
        "cname": "",
        "dlist": "test"
    }
]
```

here in `response1` `fname` is same as `response2` `hname` so based on this we need to do a mapping

`if (response1 fname == response2 hname)` then append the particular `response2` data to `dev`(`[]`) in `response1`

and the final response should be as below. how can we combine 2 responses based on the condition

```
let finalReposne =  [
    {
        "rnum": 583,
        "status": false,
        "id": 24,
        "action": "set",
        "name": "2726-23",
        "fname": [
            "xy-01"
        ],
        "dev": [
            { 
                "hName": "xy-01",
                "cname": "",
                "dlist": "test"    
            }
        ]       
    },
    {
        "rnum": 593,
        "status": false,
        "id": 12,
        "action": "set",
        "name": "2727-5",
        "fname": [
            "yz-01"
        ], 
        "dev": [
            {   
                "hName": "yz-01",
                "cname": "",
                "dlist": "test"    
            }
        ]       
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated solution in response to your comment looking to accommodate multiple `fname`s.

It first groups the elements in `response2` by `hName` using a [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) call.

It then proceeds with a `.map()` call on `response1` in which a second `.reduce()` call is used to iterate the `fname` array of the iterated object and retrieve the relevant `hName` groups. These are combined into a single array using [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and added to the object as a `dev` property.

```js
const
  response1 = [{ "rnum": 583, "status": false, "id": 24, "action": "set", "name": "2726-23", "fname": ["xy-01", "zx-02"], }, { "rnum": 593, "status": false, "id": 12, "action": "set", "name": "2727-5", "fname": ["yz-01"], }],
  response2 = [{ "hName": "yz-01", "cname": "", "dlist": "test" }, { "hName": "xy-01", "cname": "", "dlist": "test" }, { "hName": "zx-02", "cname": "", "dlist": "test" }],

  // group response2 by hName
  hnames = response2.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj.hName] = acc[obj.hName] || [];
    acc[obj.hName].push({ name: obj.hName, data: { ...obj } });
    return acc;
  }, {}),
  // map response1 and retrieve/concat hnames into dev
  result = response1.map(o => {
    const dev = o.fname.reduce((acc, fname) => (acc.concat(hnames[fname] || [])), []);

    return { ...o, dev };
  });
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

**Original Answer**

Here is a solution using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate `response1` and return a new array, and a nested [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) call to look for a match in `response2`. If a match is found we return a copy of the object using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with the match assigned to a new `dev` property, else just return a copy of the iterated object.

```js
const
  response1 = [{ "rnum": 583, "status": false, "id": 24, "action": "set", "name": "2726-23", "fname": ["xy-01"], }, { "rnum": 593, "status": false, "id": 12, "action": "set", "name": "2727-5", "fname": ["yz-01"], }],
  response2 = [{ "hName": "yz-01", "cname": "", "dlist": "test" }, { "hName": "xy-01", "cname": "", "dlist": "test" }],

  result = response1.map(o => {
    const dev = response2.find(({ hName }) => o.fname.includes(hName));
    
    return dev !== undefined ? { ...o, dev: [{ ...dev }] } : { ...o };
  });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks you This is working fine for me, If we have multiple fnames in response1 and then it should match all the hnames matching in response2 and get the result in dev[] iarray as separate objects. like below attached sample final response . Here name in dev[] refers to hname/fname of that particular data

Comment: ```[
  {
    "rnum": 583,
    "status": false,
    "id": 24,
    "action": "set",
    "name": "2726-23",
    "fname": [
      "xy-01",
   "zx-02"
    ],
    "dev": [{
 "name" : "xy-01"
 "data" :  
      {
        "hName": "xy-01",
        "cname": "",
        "dlist": "test"
      }
  },
  {
 "name" : "zx-02"
 "data" : "zx-02"  
      {
        "hName": "zx-02",
        "cname": "",
        "dlist": "test"
      }
  }
  }
    ]
  }
] 
```

Comment: we need to keep name as "name" : fname/hname and then the matching data inside "data" : {} like above. How this can be done ?

Comment: using filter I am able to get the all matching hname in dev but they are coming as "0" : { }, "1" : {}, "2" : {} , instead I need these in "data" like above response

Comment: `filter()` could definitely work if you `map()` the returned array, but you will have to iterate `response2` for every element of `response1`. By grouping `response2` first you only iterate each response array once.

Comment: thank you so much solution worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```js
let response1 = [
    {
        "rnum": 583,
        "status": false,
        "id": 24,
        "action": "set",
        "name": "2726-23",
        "fname": [
            "xy-01"
        ],
    },
    {
        "rnum": 593,
        "status": false,
        "id": 12,
        "action": "set",
        "name": "2727-5",
        "fname": [
            "yz-01"
        ],
    }
]
let response2 = [
    {
    "hName": "yz-01",
    "cname": "",
    "dlist": "test"
},
    {
    "hName": "xy-01",
    "cname": "",
    "dlist": "test"
}
]
for (i in response1) {
  for (x in response2) {
    if (response1[i].fname.includes(response2[x].hName)) {
      response1[i].dev = response2[x]
    }
  }
}
console.log(response1)
```

This is saying for every entry in `response1`, check every entry in `response2` for a matching `hName` in the `fname`.